# Convert Ruby object into HTML string with awesome_print

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to prettify an Ruby object using awesome_print so I can place this string inside an email and send it off. So in terms of code, (I know this is wrong), but here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
my_str = (ap error.object).to_str
# Do something with my_str, like stick it in a <pre> tag inside an html email.
```

How do I convert the output from ap to string? Reason I'm asking is as I noticed, ap seems to only return the object.

Comment: I'm happy with the output of awesome_print, I just want to capture it's output, and assign it to a variable, which I then want to print inside an email template, within a <pre> tag.

Comment: I'd still like to get the answer to the original question...

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem to be documented in the README.md, but if you look at the Kernel modifications the library makes here: https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print/blob/master/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/kernel.rb

You can see that in addition to the `ap` method, the *awesome_print* gem also adds an `ai` method to all objects.

```
1.9.3p392 :001 > require 'awesome_print'
 => true 
1.9.3p392 :002 > test = {a: "b"}
 => {:a=>"b"}
1.9.3p392 :003 > ap test
{
    :a => "b"
}
1.9.3p392 :006 > test.ai
 => "{\n    :a\e[0;37m => \e[0m\e[0;33m\"b\"\e[0m\n}" 
1.9.3p392 :007 > test.ai(html:true)
 => "<pre>{\n    <pre>:a</pre><kbd style=\"color:slategray\"> =&gt; </kbd><pre><kbd style=\"color:brown\">&quot;b&quot;</kbd></pre>\n}</pre>"
```

That said, the output formatting might not be that useful (the html version adds a ton of whitespace, and the non-html version has the weird terminal coloring characters), and being an undocumented feature, it's liable to break without warning in a minor version update.

The other thing worth noting in the `kernel.rb` above is that `ap` and `ai` have aliases: `awesome_print` and `awesome_inspect`.

Answer (score 2):

awesomeprint is meant for printing ASCII colors and stuff, not HTML. What I'd use is pygments gem:

```
# gem install pygments.rb
require 'pygments'

str = <<EOT
# This is an awesome comment on my rb script
a = 2
puts a
hsh = {asdf: 1, qwer: 2, uiop: 3}
EOT

Pygments.highlight str
```

https://github.com/tmm1/pygments.rb

Comment: Definitely seems like a better solution!

Comment: Not working too well though, I'm trying to output and object like so: error_html = Pygments.highlight(error.object.inspect), but it simply puts the entire output inside a <div><span> tag pair.

Comment: Guess it depends in what you are trying to pygmentize, remember adding a style tag from [these](https://github.com/richleland/pygments-css).

Comment: Requires Python as dependency.